# Node.js route error: script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, routes, mime-types

My **css** and **js** files are not found / does not load under **second route**. They do load fine under first.

Why does this happen ?

```
  // **********************  INDEX PAGE  *******************************************
    app.get('/LimeLINE', (req, res) => {
        let sTopHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/components/top.html', 'utf8')
        let sMainHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/html/index.html', 'utf8')
        let sBottomHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/components/bottom.html', 'utf8')

        // replace placeholders
        sTopHtml = sTopHtml.replace('{{title}}', 'LimeLINE: Get Started')

        res.send(sTopHtml + sMainHtml + sBottomHtml)
    })

    app.get('/LimeLINE/activate/:token', (req, res) => {
        let sToken = req.params.token;
        if (token === sToken) {
            user.activateUser(res, sToken)
        }
        let sTopHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/components/top.html', 'utf8')
        let sMainHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/html/index.html', 'utf8')
        let sBottomHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/components/bottom.html', 'utf8')
        // replace placeholders
        sTopHtml = sTopHtml.replace('{{title}}', 'LimeLINE: Welcome')
        sMainHtml = sMainHtml.replace('{{click-trigger}}', 'click-trigger')

        res.send(sTopHtml + sMainHtml + sBottomHtml)
    })
```

Comment: Could you post your html snippet where css/js files are included? I am guessing you are using relative url to import those, which is present relative to `/LimeLINE`, but not `/LimeLINE/activate/:token`.

Comment: yep. I have a folder called components and there I have my html snippets like top.html, bottom.html, which contains the path to my css/ js files, which are then located under public/css and public/js. So the path to them looks like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/main.css" />` And of course the server file above is located in the root.

Comment: Okay, that's what's going wrong here. The browser doesn't know about your folder structure. When provided with a relative path, it go for loading files relative to the current url (in address bar).

Comment: i see. Any suggestion on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using relative urls in templates which will be served from different routes. In this case same html is getting served from `http://<hostname>/LimeLINE` as well as `http://<hostname>/LimeLINE/activate/:token`. The relative url of `../css/main.css` will point to different locations in those two cases. Since the browser doesn't know about the directory structure on your server, it simply constructs the path relative to current url (in address bar).

For the first case it becomes `http://hostname/../css/main.css` which is same as `http://hostname/css/main.css`;

And in second case it is `http://<hostname>/LimeLINE/activate/../css/main.css` which is same as `http://<hostname>/LimeLINE/css/main.css`.

Just change to absolute urls (or relative to host urls, starting with /) and your code will work fine. Instead of 
`href="../css/main.css"` use `href="/css/main.css"`

Comment: but that means that I need to change my folder structure then, doesn't ?

Comment: No, not at all. You'd only need to change the link-href / script-src in all the html files. All the files can remain where they are. Express (assuming you are using expressJS, other frameworks also behave similarly) has mounted your public folder at '/' path. So `/css/main.css` automatically picks up `public/css/main.css` from your project folder.

Comment: hmm, it does actually works, without needing to change my folder structure, which I don't understand how is possible.

Comment: I know that about the static file structure, but I was thinking about my html file since that is also in a folder, so it is not absolute to css/ js folder.

Comment: I forgot to mention, when you start a relative url with a leading `/` (forward slash), the browser constructs the url relative to host name in address bar ignoring rest of the path. So a relative path of `/css/main.css` translates to `http://hostname/css/main.css` for html served through both `http://<hostname>/LimeLINE` and `http://<hostname>/LimeLINE/activate/:token` urls.